# mbsync: file-error "not a regular file"

Tags: email, emacs, gmail, isync, mbsync

I'm using notmuch-mode from within Emacs to send email using isync/mbsync through Gmail. However, every time I send email from within Emacs, I get this error:

Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "not a regular file" "/Users/peter/Dropbox/mail/gmail/sent")
  insert-file-contents("/Users/peter/Dropbox/mail/gmail/sent" nil 0 100)
  mail-file-babyl-p("/Users/peter/Dropbox/mail/gmail/sent")
  message-output("/Users/peter/Dropbox/mail/gmail/sent")
  message-do-fcc()
  message-send()
  send-message-without-bullets()
  call-interactively(send-message-without-bullets nil nil)
  command-execute(send-message-without-bullets)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I can share relevant details from my .mbsyncrc if that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered on the notmuch mailing list, you need to use `notmuch-mua-send` rather than calling `message-send` directly.